# Should node JS projects that do not use TS still install the @type packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, types, package.json

I'm wondering if this is why half my IDE doesn't work... I'm working in an 8 year react app built with JS without the types, navigation is a nightmare. I tried to install @types/react but it wouldn't let me, it conflicted with backbone, an old limb hanging off the app with gangrene.

Thus, do these type dev only installations provide any benefit to the developer if writing a JS app, or are they only beneficial to TS projects?

My suspicion is there is some benefit to imports and IDE functionality, but obviously not typing.

Using latest intelliJ Idea, trying to cleanup a monstrous project.

Comment: Types definitely help with IDE functionality, but that's about it if you're not using TS.